# How to show the world your country

Tags: society, culture, secret-society

In my story, I need to make a country (don't need U.N. approval, just significant power related to a weak country) with 1,000 or less people, lead by a hypnotist (just accept this, I know it is unrealistic). I need some way for the US to not attack. I'm thinking a mix of Fortune 500 high-level employees, media workers (55% TV, 20% internet, 10% radio, 15% newspaper), and a few ambassadors. Assume the groundwork is in place, what would work as a "grand reveal"?

Comment: This seems rather broad. What specifically about the country do you want people to address?

Comment: How it could exist, but anything about the rise of this country will work.

Comment: Like they take over NYC and make it a country?  Or they form a country-type entity with no land?  What is a "country" to you?

Comment: Just an area with political or military power

Comment: Do you mean inside a developed country?  Are you talking secession or in a destabilized area?

Comment: I'm talking secession

Comment: How to show the world your country:  Like this : https://www.ricksteves.com/watch-read-listen/video/tv-show/edinburgh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a country is *easy*.  Get a bunch of people together, put up some border markers, and tell everyone else you're now the United Kingdom of Whateveria.  Done.

The problem is *keeping* it.  As the US Civil War showed, that's a much more difficult proposition.  You need some extremely strong leverage to stop the US from just marching in and pointing out that, no, this is still part of the US, and enforcing that with a standing army and big guns.  So the question is more about what type of leverage you want to use.

**Economic**

If the country controls a ton of money/companies, or has access to something really important, they might be able to effectively hold the US hostage and prevent it from invading.

**Military**

It's difficult to imagine a small country like this being a significant traditional military power.  However, they might have some sort of special weapon that they can use to enforce a truce - kind of a [MAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction)-type situation.  This could be anything from nuclear or antimatter bombs, to a super-virus they can release.  But either way, the world would need to know that they 1) have it and 2) are willing to use it.

**Political**

If they had the right allies, your group might count on international pressure to keep themselves independent.  That might mean cuddling up to some rather nasty countries, though.

**Public Opinion**

If the group in question has broad public support for some reason, it might be difficult for the US to build sufficient political will for an invasion.  Especially since footage of the attack would likely be broadcast world wide.

**Combination**

Probably the best approach is a combination of as much of the above as possible.  Use your economic power to control public opinion and bribe key officials, and make friends over seas.  Link as many US companies as possible to your country, so if they do invade and destroy you they'll attack their own economy as well, creating a MAD-type scenario.  Buy, or at least *appear* to buy, nuclear weapons and set them up as failsafes.

Comment: So ambassadors, Fortune 500 members, and nuclear commanders would work?

Comment: @TheMystery: Yes.  Although I find it to be a bit of a stretch that you could keep a conspiracy that large secret for long enough to accomplish this goal.  The original core must be as small possible.

Comment: Makes sense. The only reason I'm not checking this is to make sure nobody makes a better one.

Comment: In light of the small size and the military considerations, I vote for naming it "Duchy of Grand Fenwick".

Answer (score 1):

**You simply define your borders.**

Calling something a country is a generally pointless designation if it's unrecognized. If recognition is not required, and it likely wouldn't be given, then it's your word against theirs. Other countries won't officially recognize yours as a country and yours won't officially recognize their ability to decide that.

If you don't try to get recognition, enforce your borders, or really do anything besides name your land, then people probably won't even care. If you do try to enforce your borders, then without recognition your succession is simply an act of violence inside the country you're trying to succeed from. There will be a "war" (though only you would call it that, since the government of the parent country doesn't recognize you as a country to war with) and your group will be disbanded or killed.

There are eight million people in NYC and more than half a million in DC. Your band of ten thousand won't be a threat to them. If you *do* threaten them the US government will destroy you.

Answer (score 1):

CGP Grey talks a little about this on his video for [Texas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S92fTz_-kQE). To summarize: such a country would need to the approval of the United States of America to exist. The Constitution does not mention anything about secession, but the [Articles of Confederation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._state#Secession) simply states that the USA "shall be perpetual."

The US Supreme Court decided in [Texas v. White](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_v._White) that states cannot secede from the Union. That is, unless rebellion or the consent of the states allow the secession to happen. Such an act would normally mean war, and the [US outspends *every nation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_budget_of_the_United_States#Comparison_with_other_countries) on their military budget. I doubt a single city, much less than a single state, can withstand the military might of America.

There is a small glimmer of a loophole for this to happen. If this secret society manages two things, this can happen. (1) The city in question becomes a state and (2) all the other states in the union want that new state *out*. This would be legal as far as the rulings in Texas v. White go.

Finally, countries are recognized as such by people recognizing them as such. [CGP grey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AivEQmfPpk), once again, has a video about this and its intricacies. In theory, if enough people think New York is a country on its own, and one day the UN recognizes it as such, it would totally be a country, although not in the eyes of USA. Taiwan (Or Chinese Taipei) is a good example of this.

Comment: I find this really amusing.  "Let's found a city and become so obnoxious that every other state in the US kicks us out."  But I think they wouldn't allow it regardless, just to avoid setting the precedent.  It's like paying off a terrorist, you're just opening yourself up to more pain the long run.

Answer (score 0):

This has been tired from time to time, with so called "micro nations" being built in the English Channel on the remains of anti aircraft platforms built outside the 3 mile limit during WWII. Starting around the 1960's they were occupied from time to time by people declaring themselves independent nations (like Sealand. See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Sealand)

Since the platforms were abandoned at the time and outside of territorial waters when claimed (this was before the internationally recognized boundaries and economic zones came into existence) there was perhaps a legal justification (although most people might consider this more an acto of salvage). At any rate, Sealand is not recognized by anyone and the UK seems inclined to simply ignore this so long as the Sealanders are not too annoying or call attention to themselves. However, there is nothing to stop the Royal Navy from sending a platoon of Marines to evict everyone and engineers to demolish the structure as a hazard to navigation. First rule; any sovereign nation needs to be able to defend itself.

Seasteading is another idea where ships set sail and essentially never come back. The practical issues are fairly clear, including the service and support of the ship itself, and what sort of economic activity would allow a relatively self-sufficient existence on the high seas. the legal issues of how a "sea stead" would sever their relationship from the land is also interesting to think about; every ship has a port or nation of registry, and declaring you no longer are bound by that designation also severs you from other things, like protection from pirates and salvagers (an unregistered ship might qualify as salvage for an unscrupulous deep sea salvage team, especially if the port *they* go to is also not too inclined to worry about legalities). More practical concerns like access to the international postal and banking system, or registering domain names from an unregistered ship might also put a crimp in the idea of seasteading. A "Seastead" which carries enough weaponry to defend itself from pirates or nations who decide they don't want a sea stead sailing offshore will be a warship, and the USN, PLAN, Japanese Self Defense Force and other navies will certainly object to the idea of an "undeclared" warship anywhere on the sea lanes.

This also relates to the idea of space colonies declaring independence. Space colonies will be self sufficient by design, but since they will be hugely expensive and have the potential (long term) to damage the entire Earth should they somehow get hold of an asteroid, they will most likely remain under very tight control of the Earth. Like the micro nation or seastead, they won't have much of a way to defend their sovereignty, so becoming an independent nation will take a lot more than declaring it so.

Heinlein's "The Moon is a Harsh Mistress" is a perfect example of that; the Moon is unable to declare and keep its independence until the rebels take over the mass driver and start dropping rocks on the Earth to demonstrate they can keep others from taking what is theirs.